# Does Azure automated backup for SQL database on Azure VM have way to detect log chain?

Tags: sql-server, backup, transaction-log, azure-vm

I have SQL server on Azure VM.

If I enable Azure automated backups for the SQL server on Azure VM to backup the dbs (full/diff/log), and suppose if an admin performs a manual log backup (which effectively will break the log chain of Azure database backup), then, is there any alerting feature provided by Azure?

Comment: how exactly you enable automated backups for SQL Server on Azure VM ? (Where do you go on Azure portal / which feature you use ? )

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/backup-restore?view=azuresql#automated